# Strange @vue-cli 3 error with package dependency @vue/eslint-config-standard@^3.0.1

Tags: npm, vue-cli

It's hard to leave this one here without much comment - but I've just upgraded to the latest version of the @vue-cli and I'm receiving the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @vue/eslint-config-standard@^3.0.1
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Looking at the nam site - eslint-config-standard v3.0.1 or higher doesn't even exist yet!?

For detail:

vue-cli ***v3.0.1***, npm ***v6.4.0*** and node ***v8.11.3***

My project app configuration is:

```
? Please pick a preset: Manually select features
? Check the features needed for your project: Babel, PWA, Vuex, CSS Pre-processors, Linter, Unit, E2E
? Pick a CSS pre-processor (PostCSS, Autoprefixer and CSS Modules are supported by default): SCSS/SASS
? Pick a linter / formatter config: Prettier
? Pick additional lint features: Lint on save
? Pick a unit testing solution: Mocha
? Pick a E2E testing solution: Cypress
? Where do you prefer placing config for Babel, PostCSS, ESLint, etc.? In package.json
```

Comment: I got this earlier today, I used eslint-config-standard@^3.0.0

Comment: @wadclapp - Do you know how I would specify this when creating a new vue project?

Answer (score 0):

your package.json should be this:

this is my config file:

- `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.4",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^4.0.0",

    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "postcss-px2rem": "^0.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-cube-ui": "^0.2.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  },
……
```

- `.eslintrc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: ["plugin:vue/essential", "@vue/standard"],
  rules: {
    "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
    "space-before-function-paren": 0,
    indent: 0
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "babel-eslint"
  }
};
```

Also, I delete the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` files.

In the end, `npm install`.

Hope, can help you.

> The `@vue/eslint-config-standard` config is specifically designed to be used by `vue-cli` setups and is not meant for outside use. You don't need to do extra configuration.